# DI resolves service by Interface of object and not by actual type

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

Let assume that we have following code

We have commands that all implement same interface

```
public interface ICommand {}
```

and that we have Command handlers that implement following interface

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T: ICommand {}
```

Actual implementations of command handlers are registered to DI.

Now, if we have method that builds Commands based on some condition

```
public ICommand BuildCommand()
{
   if(someCondition) return new CommandA();
   else return new CommandB();
}
```

and we use it in code like this

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
  IServiceProvider _serviceProvder; 
  public void method_1()
  {
    ICommand command = BuildCommand();
    HandleCommand(command);
  }

  public void HandleCommand<T>(T command) 
  {
    var handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICommandHandler<T>>();
    handler.Handle();
  }
```

if will throw an error stating that it cannot resolve service
`ICommandHandler<ICommand>`

I would expect DI to resolve by actual type (either CommandA or CommandB). How to get past this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would expect DI to resolve by actual type (either CommandA or CommandB). How to get past this?

The DI Container can't resolve this in that situation, because of the following reasons:

- At compile time, you are supplying `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` to the `GetRequiredService<T>` method; it is given no runtime information that would allow it to spot anything different.
- When asked to resolve `ICommandHandler<ICommand>`, the container can't return anything else, because `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` is a different type to `ICommandHandler<CommandA>`. And even if it could, the request would even be ambiguous, because it could result in either an `ICommandHandler<CommandA>` *or* an `ICommandHandler<CommandB>`. Which one should it return?
- It's impossible to cast an `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` to `ICommandHandler<CommandA>` or vise versa in .NET, unless you make `ICommandHandler<T>` [variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) (i.e. you need to mark `T` with either `in` or `out`).

The solution here is to resort to using Reflection. For instance:

```cs
public void HandleCommand(ICommand command) 
{
    Type handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());

    dynamic handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);

    handler.Handle((dynamic)command);
}
```

In this example I'm using the `dynamic` keyword for simplicity. There are pros and cons to using this keyword. Obvious downside is of course loss of compile-time support. This is, IMO, not a big issue, because you would typically only have a single place in the application that calls command handlers using reflection, and that code can easily be (unit) tested. A more important downside, however, is that it will fail if a resolved handler implementation is internal - even when the `ICommandHandler<T>` is defined as `public`. This is caused by the C# runtime binder mechanism that is used behind the scenes by the C# compiler. I struggled with this unfortunate behavior many times.

So instead of using dynamic, you can also invoke the method using the Reflection API:

```cs
public void HandleCommand(ICommand command) 
{
    Type handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());

    object handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);

    MethodInfo method = handlerType.GetMethod("Handle");

    try
    {
        method.Invoke(handler, new object[] { command });
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
    {
        // When a Reflection Invoke call fails, the original exception
        // is wrapped in a TargetInvocationException. This complicates
        // error handling by consumers, which is why we 'unwrap' that
        // exception and rethrow the original exception. The only
        // to do this without losing the original stack trace is using
        // The ExceptionDispatchInfo class.
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
    }
}
```

What you're effectively doing here is dispatching commands to the appropriate command handler. The same can be done using queries. The two code examples above are slight alterations of code from an old [blog post of mine](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/queries/) about queries.

A third option, which is what I use in my current projects is to introduce a wrapper class:

```cs
public void HandleCommand(ICommand command)
{
    var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());

    object handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);

    var wrapper = (IWrapper)Activator.CreateInstance(
        typeof(Wrapper<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType()),
        new[] { handler });

    wrapper.Handle(command);
}

internal interface IWrapper
{
    void Handle(ICommand command);
}

internal sealed record Wrapper<TCommand>(
    ICommandHandler<TCommand> Handler) : IWrapper
{
    public void Handle(ICommand command) => this.Handler.Handle((TCommand)command);
}
```

Alternatively, this `Wrapper<T>` can be registered in your container instead, which allows you to resolve the `Wrapper<TCommand>` from the container instead of calling `Activator.CreateInstance`. This improves performance (a bit), but forces the `Wrapper<T>` to be registered in the container.